# Does Database Inherit Limitations after upgrade?

Tags: database, postgresql

I created a database in PostgreSQL 12, after adding data, I ran the below query

```
SELECT w.machine_name, 
SUM(l.reward_points) as points
FROM loyalty l
JOIN warehouses w
ON l.machine_ip = w.machine_ip
GROUP BY w.machine_name
ORDER BY points DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

I got this error "***syntax error at or near "WITH" LINE 8:    FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES***"
When I searched online, I learnt "WITH TIES" is not present in PostgreSQL 12.
I upgrade PostgreSQL on my system from 12 to 13, after the upgrade, the error still persists.

My question is, did my database still posses the same limitation as from before?

If Yes, what can I do to fix it. Will deleting it and recreating it fix it?

Is there an alternative way to fix this without deleting the database?

Comment: did you check the version you're now using? SELECT VERSION();

Comment: Thank you @FrankHeikens. Apparently it was still using 12 by default. I have completely remove 12 and everything works as expected.